# How to show link to download a file contained in deployment war?

Tags: java, tomcat

I am deploying a war to a tomcat web server. (struts 1, not 2)

It needs to display a link for the user to download a static document that is to be included in the exported war.

What folder inside the deployment war should I store the document in, and how should the url link to the file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://localhost:8080/SampleWar/sample.html

consider sample.html file in webapp folder

[image]

your file should be inside webapp , but this way anyone can access no security , for example you can also have sample.txt or etc

Comment: That's a lot easier than the other technique I found, which was to write an action class just for a static download